# What are the different ways of returning / creating JSON in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to understand the different ways to create Json Objects Server Side, and pass them to the client.

In my travels, I have noted a couple distinct ways of doing this. But due to the overwhelmingly dynamic nature of Javascript, I am having a hard time understanding what the differences between these two examples are.

**One takes an anonymous object, the other takes any object, and a string such as "application/json"**

Can someone explain this to me, not just at the questions level but on a more fundamental level?

And what is the purpose of "application/json" in that approach?

Due to not understanding this properly, I often find myself having to fiddle with things for a while to get the working due to data formatting issues.

**Method I have seen 1**

```
public JsonResult returnJson1(){

  var objectOfAnyKind = /* Do stuff to get data */

  return Json(objectOfAnyKind, "application/json");

}
```

**Method I have seen 2**

```
public JsonResult returnJson2(){

  var objectOfAnyKind = /* Do stuff to get data */

  return Json(new { result = objectOfAnyKind });

}
```

Any explanations will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Method one will produce JSON something like this `{"prop": "value"}` and the second one wraps that in some more JSON `{"result": {"prop": "value"}}`. The best way to see what happens is to try it out...

Comment: `return Json(objectOfAnyKind, "application/json");` What does intellisense tell you that second parameter means?

Comment: Thanks @mjwills, I actually didn't think to do that. But that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @WilliamD Doesn't it answer `And what is the purpose of "application/json" in that approach?`?